# C++ Compiler Error; Namespace issue I guess

Tags: c++, namespaces, compiler-errors

The error I get is "No member named detail in namespace ChessGame. Here is the relevant code

```
//ChessPiece.h
namespace ChessGame 
{

class ChessBoard;

namespace detail
{
    class IChessPieceEnums{
    public:
        enum PieceType{PAWN, KNIGHT, BISHOP, ROOK, QUEEN, KING};
        enum PieceDirection{ UP = 1 , DOWN  = -1};
        enum PieceId{ WHITE_PIECE_ID, BLACK_PIECE_ID };
    };
}

//represents an abstract chess piece interface
class IChessPiece : public detail::IChessPieceEnums
{
public:   
 ///...
}

} // end namespace


//GameBoard.h
#include "ChessPiece.h"
namespace ChessGame 
{

 class IChessPiece;

 class ChessBoard
 {
  public:
    /*********ERROR OCCURS ON THIS FUNCTION************/
    bool isOccupiedWithEnemy(int row, int col,const ChessGame::detail::IChessPieceEnums::PieceId& pieceId);
 }
}
```

Any idea guys?

EDIT: Another minimal example :

//Piece.h

```
#ifndef TestProject_C___Piece_h
#define TestProject_C___Piece_h

#include "Board.h"

namespace Foo {
namespace detail{
    struct PieceEnums{
        enum PieceID{ ID1, ID2 };
    };
}

class Board;

class Piece{
public:
    void foo(Board& b)const;
};
}
#endif
```

//board.h

```
 #ifndef TestProject_C___Board_h
 #define TestProject_C___Board_h

 #include "Piece.h"


namespace Foo {
class Piece;

class Board{
    bool isOcc(int x, int y,const detail::PieceEnums::PieceID pid)const;
};
}

#endif
```

And the error is 'Use of undeclared identifier detail

Note that this is across multiple files, so maybe its a problem with linkage?

Comment: Fixing the syntax errors, this compiles fine.

Comment: Why is pieceId a reference? Are you per chance calling osOccupiedWithEnemy with a literal PieceId?

Comment: @pezcode: yea it doesn't need to be, I guess. I will be calling it by giving it a location(x,y) and a literal PieceId, yes

Answer (score 1):

To specify the desired name directly, say either `detail::IChessPieceEnums::PieceId` or `::ChessGame::detail::IChessPieceEnums::PieceId`, but preferably the former. However, your present syntax is actually fine, too, since search resumes in the global namespace if a name can't be found.

Comment: I tried both and get the same error. It's not finding 'detail' namespace for some reason

Comment: Did you fix your syntax errors? You need semicolons at the end of class definitions.

Comment: Yes, it was a type in the above post

Comment: @user814628: Please post a real, minimal example then. Try to cut it down to the smallest piece of code that is otherwise correct and has only this problem. So far I cannot reproduce it and your error lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a solution. The solution is to put the namespace detail in its own file called detail.h. That way, piece.h and board.h needs to include details.h to use it. That worked.

And the problem with the original post is that there is a circular reference. That is causing trouble somehow. Would love an explanation.

Comment: Oh the problem was that I was including piece.h before board.h, I needed to switch them around.